# Почему выдает такую ошибку php?

Tags: php

есть простой метод

```
public static function exists($name){

    if(isset($_SESSION[$name])){
      return true;
    }

  }
```

Почему он выдает такую ошибку

```
Illegal offset type in isset or empty in ... Session.php on line 12

Строка 12 - это if(isset($_SESSION[$name])){
```

Он ругается именно на Проверку $_Session[$name], причем если проверять лишь name то все окей

Comment: ну так ты выведи $name и посмотри, что там. А потому подумай, имеет ли смысл писать $_SESSION[$name] в таком случае

Answer (score 0, accepted):

правильнее будет если php версии 7+

```
public static function exists(string $name=''): bool
{
  if(!$name){
    return false;
  }
  return isset($_SESSION[$name]);
}
```

защитное программирование заключается в том чтобы проверять всегда входящие данные
Рекомендую прочесть книгу Совершенный код, чтобы не попадаться на такое

Comment: Надо же так извратить смысл прочитанного. Защитное программироавне состоит в чем угодно, только не в заметании проблемы под ковёр. У автора сейчас нормальный код, который сигнализирует о проблемах, которые надо **решать**. А выему дали затычку, чтобы код падал молча, и было непонятно, в чем проблема. Проверять входные данные мало. **Надо еще что-то делать, если они неправильные.**